# Gradle configuration for OpenAPI Generator

Tags: java, openapi-generator

When using OpenAPI generator with Gradle, I would expect to emit the gendered sources to the standard directory used by other source generator plugins. Something like the Maven generated-sources.

So far I haven't been able to do so, particularly to limit the generation to Java source classes instead of a whole “archetype project”.

It seems that the OpenAPI Gradle plugin workflow isn't thought out the same as the Maven one.

Is there a configuration flag to omit generation of all non-java code and to do so in an “generated sources” folder such as /out/production/generated/?

Comment: There is a ignorefile you an add https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/customization#ignore-file-format

Comment: All generators support the `outputDir` property (equivalent to `output` in our Maven plugin). The gradle plugin is perhaps "more correct" than the Maven plugin because it uses OpenAPI Generator core's defaults rather than defining others. A common gradle workflow would be to generate to a path relative to the project root, rather than a `generated-sources` directory. Feel free to open an issue on the repo and the core team will work to align or document this a little better.

Answer (score 9):

In case this is of help to anyone, I have built this skeleton of a Gradle and OpenAPI Generator project which generates API and model files directly into the project source file hierarchy.

It uses the following configuration:

```
openApiGenerate {
    generatorName = "spring"
    inputSpec = "..."
    outputDir = "$projectDir"
    apiPackage = "..."
    modelPackage = "..."
    configOptions = [
            interfaceOnly: "true",
            openApiNullable: "false",
            skipDefaultInterface: "true"
    ]
    globalProperties = [
            apis: "",
            models: ""
    ]
}
```

The example is [here](https://github.com/alwaysbemark/spring-boot-openapi-generator).

Comment: the best tip, this options in `configOptions` help to get rid from the junk generated by the framework