# Generate only REST interfaces for spring boot with openapi-generator-gradle-plugin

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, gradle, openapi-generator

I tried to generate interfaces from a swagger file we need to implement. It's provided from an external source. I usually use contract first, but didn't do that in a long time with java/kotlin.

I already have a project set up and want to have as much control of my code as possible. I tried to use `openapi-generator-gradle-plugin` with `kotlin-spring` or `spring` generator, to generate the interfaces (the import part).

Best would be Interfaces with spring related annotations (`RequestMapping`s etc.) and at least just the interfaces. But it seems, the generator also generates a "little application" (with gradle/maven file, SpringBootApp, README.md ...).

I don't have the code anymore, but was pretty sure, the last time I did this, it was easy possible to just generate interfaces, but can't remember which generator or plugin I used.

So my question is, did I miss something or is just creating interfaces not an issue anymore? Does everyone wants to do scaffolding here?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57477645/gradle-configuration-for-openapi-generator the examples in this question will do what you need.

Answer (score 2):

I use the openapi-generator-maven-plugin with `<interfaceOnly>true</interfaceOnly>` configOption. It should be similar in gradle with kotlin-spring generator

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
  <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>5.0.0-beta</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>1</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>generate</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <inputSpec>openapi.json</inputSpec>
        <generatorName>spring</generatorName>
        <modelPackage>modelPackage</modelPackage>
        <apiPackage>apiPackage</apiPackage>
        <invokerPackage>invokerPackage</invokerPackage>
        <configOptions>
          <sourceFolder>target</sourceFolder>
          <interfaceOnly>true</interfaceOnly>
        </configOptions>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: This approach doesn't create the @SpringBootApplication Class, but also creates a pom.xml and a README.md. So the approach the generator takes is to create a whole project instead of just the interfaces. It literally ignores "interfaceOnly". Does the maven plugin has the same behaviour?

Comment: is the same behaviour, but i generate them in target folder and i import the classes in my project with @ComponentScan(basePackages = {"openapi.project","com.project"}) and then you can use the generated code

Comment: This is an example without <interfaceOnly> https://github.com/Jiratech/boilerplates-java-openapi. If you don't add <interfeceOnly> it generates a project that will also have swagger-ui out of the box

Comment: Ok, so you just ignore the other stuff? I think that could work for the spring generator. Unfortunately the kotlin-spring generator also generates the SpringBootApp which would also be compiled and packeged into the final JAR.

Answer (score 2):

I added the following properties to my `openApiGenerate` task:

```
    globalProperties =[
            apis: '',
            models: '',
    ]
```

which solved the issue for me.

Comment: So simple and elegant

Comment: works perfectly with gradle groovy, thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you are using gradle with a `build.gradle.kts` you can use this [openapi-generator](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator) plugin task to generate the swagger code.
It does the same thing as the swagger codegen plugin:

```kotlin
plugins {
    id("org.openapi.generator") version "5.1.1"
}

openApiGenerate {
    generatorName.set("spring")
    inputSpec.set("$rootDir/src/main/resources/petstore.yaml")
    outputDir.set("$buildDir/generated/")
    configFile.set("$rootDir/src/main/resources/api-config.json")


    globalProperties.set(mapOf(
        Pair("apis", ""), //no value or comma-separated api names
        Pair("models", ""), //no value or comma-separated api names
    ))
}
```

The `apis` generated from the paths in your swagger. The `api-config.json` has the settings of your [generator](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/docs/generators/spring.md).
and then you need to add the generated classes to your sourceSet by doing:

```kotlin
configure<SourceSetContainer> {
    named("main") {
        java.srcDir("$buildDir/generated/src/main/java")
    }
}
```

Finally make sure you generate the swagger files before compiling:

```kotlin
tasks.withType<org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile> {
    dependsOn("openApiGenerate")
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "11"
}
```